# microsoft partner center sdk finding nonprofit customers

Tags: c#, sdk

I have a console application project with c# that connect to [Microsoft Partner](https://partnercenter.microsoft.com) Center with SDK and do something like creating customers, listing customers, get subscriptions... etc. Microsoft has a customer type named 'Nonprofit', i have to list this nonprofit customers but i couldn't find any information about how i can understand a customer is nonprofit or not.

[The  the documentation and samples about sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/create-a-customer) that provided by microsoft doesn't has any information about this topic.

Does anybody has any idea about how i can find a nonprofit customer by microsoft partner center sdk ?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could show us your progress so far, in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills I am not sure i can do this; my problem is not about coding, i don't know any information about this kind of customer at sdk documentation. I am goin to add the samples of microsoft already provided. Mine progress are almost same.

Answer (score -1):

True, cannot find much information about Charity (non profit) offer.
I am facing problem while placing an order for Charity subscriptions using api + c#. 
Error : "Offer/Subcription XXXXXX is not available for purchase."

Note : I can easily place order for Academic,Corporate,Government using the same code.